# How to avoid writing explicit port number (8443) in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, ssl, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application (arbejdsdag.dk) running on a DigitalOcean droplet. I have sucessfully installed a LetsEncrypt SSL certificate and that works too.

However, I am unable to access the site unless I explicitly add the SSL port after the URL.

So:
arbejdsdag.dk:8443  works fine
arbejdsdag.dk       returns a 404 (Not found) error

I also have a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

```
  @Bean
  @Profile("PROD") 
  public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
          SecurityConstraint securityConstraint = new SecurityConstraint();
          securityConstraint.setUserConstraint("CONFIDENTIAL");
          SecurityCollection collection = new SecurityCollection();
          collection.addPattern("/*");
          securityConstraint.addCollection(collection);
          context.addConstraint(securityConstraint);
        }
      };

    tomcat.addAdditionalTomcatConnectors(initiateHttpConnector());
    return tomcat;
  }


  @Profile("PROD") 
  private Connector initiateHttpConnector() {
    Connector connector = new Connector("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol");
    connector.setScheme("http");
    connector.setPort(8080);
    connector.setSecure(false);
    connector.setRedirectPort(8443);

    return connector;
  }
```

The port is set to 8443 in the application properties as pr. the Spring Boot documentation.

```
server.port=8443
```

I want to be able to access the site by just typing the URL without having to explicitly adding the port number. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The port must be `443` for browsers to use https by default without a port number. Change

```
server.port=8443
```

to

```
server.port=443
```

But note that you will have to run the application as a privileged user to open a port below 1000 on a *NIX based system.

Comment: OK. I have changed to 443 now, but my application fails to load due to another application using port 443.
   `netstat -tupln`
shows Apache2 listening on 443. 
`tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      2481/apache2 tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN     2481/apache2`
Is there a way to resolve this?

Comment: Stop apache2, or change your configuration to make it a [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html).